# RubyMine is showing the error message: "Error running Development: MyProject: Rails 3.x launcher script was found instead of Rails 4.x one"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubymine

I'm updating my project from Rails 3.2.12 to 4.0.0.
I made all necessary corrections but when I try to execute my app using RubyMine 5.4 I'm receiving the message below:

> Error running Development: MyProject: Rails 3.x launcher script was found instead of Rails 4.x one. You need '/Users/stackoverflowuser/RubymineProjects/MyProject/bin/rails' script to launch Rails server. Please update server launcher according to Rails 4.x documentation.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

"Hack" solution:

1. Create a new Rails 4 project: `rails new MyTestRails4Project`
2. Copy the bin folder that is within the MyTestRails4Project
3. Paste bin folder inside the project that has just been migrated to Rails 4

**Update**

If the first solution doesn't work, as *RiPuk* suggested:

Run the rake task: `rake rails:update`

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer is a bit of a hack - it sounds like you've not finished the upgrade of your project from Rails 3 -> Rails 4.

First thing to do is to run the rake task that interactively updates various files (environments, configs etc) to Rails 4:

```
rake rails:update
```

Then assuming that you want to use Spring (of course you do!), run this:

```
spring binstub --all
```

Comment: Maybe is a "hack", however is the most simple solution. Your solution probably will work too, but need to use Spring at all, as you know many people can't use spring, so my "hack" works with spring or without spring. Anyway your solution is another solution, so, I upvoted.

Comment: The key part of my answer was the use of `rake rails:update` - which is the correct way to ensure that the bins get put in the right place for Rails 4, when upgrading from Rails 3. The Spring part was a free bonus, should you want to use it ;-)

Comment: @danilodeveloper Hi, yep, I do all my dev in the latest version of Rubymine.

Comment: @danilodeveloper, using `rails:update` (or its more limited `rails:update:bin`) is _concretely_ better, as it's upstream-supported and thus guaranteed to continue to work (or get a deprecation notice or documented migration path) with future releases. Copying around `bin/` contents may or may not work in the future -- if they add new dependencies on other parts of tree or project structure, the manual approach leaves you on your own.

Comment: I don't think it can be easier than running a rake task. Thanks Dave!

Answer (score 3):

it's a problem related to the IDE configutration, one quick solution to this is:

1. close the project
2. remove .idea folder
3. open project
4. Profit!

Answer (score -1):

if it does not work, try to create a new project (rails new project) and copy the db and app folder from your original project to the new project and create the database using:

> rake db:schema:load

I hope this helps.